# Gregwar Bundle on MAMP vs online

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to figuring out what might be the reason why Gregwar Bundle is throwing an exception online while on my local development environment everything is fine.

Locally:
[image]

vs

online:
[image]

Please note that on my local machine I'm using MAMP (Apache 2.2.29 / PHP 7.0.0) and on the server side I have Linux (PHP 5.6.24). I'm surprised with this issue because I'm used to deploying Symfony2-based websites online on Linux environment with Gregwar bundle in them without having to deal with this kind of issue.

Any clues or suggestions please?

Check out the way Gregwar bundle's methods are being called in my template:

```html
{% extends "APPlatformBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block title %}Accueil - {{ parent() }}{% endblock %}

{% block platform_body %}
    {% block header %}
        {% include('APPlatformBundle:Common:header.html.twig') with { active :'home'} %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block carousel %}
        {#{% include('APPlatformBundle:Common:carousel.html.twig') %}#}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
        <div class="container">
            <div class="line section-title center" style="text-align: center;color:white;text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #f58222, 0 0 25px green, 0 0 5px #f58222;">
                <!--<hr class="styledLine">-->

                    <h2>CONSULTEZ NOS MODULES CI-DESSOUS OU TOUT LE CATALOGUE COMPLET</h2>


                <hr class="styledLine">
                <div class="row pull-right">
                    Le Catalogue complet : <a href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/ytf3rfl3vmz8jue/Catalogue.pdf?dl=0"><img src="{{ image('bundles/applatform/images/PDFicon.png').cropResize(32,32) }}"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 heading-colored"><p style="margin-bottom: 50px;"></p></div><br><br>
                <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default panel-home">
                        <div class="panel-heading thumbnail">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="">En savoir plus</h4>
                                <p class="">
                                    <a class="btn btn-success" href="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/d93866a99a15e6ad3c79732a1/files/Module_8_Communication_Te_le_communication_Marketing_et_De_veloppement_commercial.pdf" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Vous pouvez consulter et/ou télécharger ce module"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save-file" style="color:#f58222;"></i> Consulter ce module</a><br/><br/>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/d93866a99a15e6ad3c79732a1/files/Fiche_d_inscription_modifie_.pdf" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Téléchargez, remplissez puis renvoyez-nous cette fiche par mail"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save-file" style="color:#f58222;"></i> Télécharger la fiche d'inscription</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <img src="{{ image('bundles/applatform/images/com-telecom-marketing.png').cropResize(275,183) }}" alt="" height="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body panel-body-home">
                            <h5 id="modules" class="heading-colored">Communication –Télécommunication – Marketing & Développement commercial</h5>
                            <div>
                                <!--
                                <p>
                                    <p>La FONCTION COMMUNICATION d'entreprise repose sur trois enjeux :</p>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>donner du sens à la stratégie de l'entreprise et permettre à chacun de se l'approprier et de la décliner au quotidien ;</li>
                                        <li>concourir au développement de l'activité par la mise en œuvre d'outils et de techniques de communication ;</li>
                                        <li>faciliter les relations de coopération et de confiance entre les acteurs internes et externes.</li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <p>Chyqat, à travers les Modules qui vous sont proposés ici, vous offre la possibilité de maitriser tous les contours de cette Fonction essentielle, de positionner votre entreprise et de posséder toutes armes de succès de votre profession de spécialiste de la Communication acteurs internes et externes.</p>

                                </p>
                                -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer heading-colored"><a  class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Vous pouvez consulter et/ou télécharger ce module"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" style="color: #f58222;"></i> En savoir plus</a> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default panel-home">
                        <div class="panel-heading thumbnail">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="">En savoir plus</h4>
                                <p class="">
                                    <a class="btn btn-success" href="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/d93866a99a15e6ad3c79732a1/files/Module_10_Budget_Conto_le_budge_taire_et_Conto_le_de_gestion.pdf" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Vous pouvez consulter et/ou télécharger ce module"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file" style="color:#f58222;"></i> Consulter ce module</a><br/><br/>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/d93866a99a15e6ad3c79732a1/files/Fiche_d_inscription_modifie_.pdf" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Téléchargez, remplissez puis renvoyez-nous cette fiche par mail"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file" style="color:#f58222;"></i> Télécharger la fiche d'inscription</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <img src="{{ image('bundles/applatform/images/budget2.jpg').forceResize(275,183) }}" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body panel-body-home">
                            <h5 class="heading-colored">Budget - Contôle budgétaire & Contrôle de gestion </h5>
                            <!--<p>
                                En cette période de crise économique et financière, les entreprises surveillent plus que jamais les aspects financiers de leurs activités. En tant que garants de la rentabilité, les services comptables et financiers sont particulièrement exposés. La prise en compte, le plus tôt possible, des désirs des utilisateurs d’information financière dans l’élaboration des outils et des procédures est une étape indispensable dans la construction d’un système financier stable et efficace.
                                Aussi convient-il de se montrer réactif et de s’adapter à l’exigence accrue demandée à tous les membres des directions financières bien au-delà de la simple logique de réduction des coûts exigée par la crise.

                            </p>-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer heading-colored"><a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Vous pouvez consulter et/ou télécharger ce module"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" style="color: #f58222;"></i> En savoir plus</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: You haven't given much to go on. Have you checked if your PHP versions are the same locally and on the server. I'm guessing you are using MAMP locally, what is your online version hosted on?

Comment: @Alex L Thanks for your answer. Actually, on my local machine I'm using MAMP and PHP 7.0.0, and on the server side I have PHP 5.6 and LAMP. I'm surprised with this issue because I'm used to deploying Symfony2-based websites online on Linux environment with Gregwar bundle in them.

Comment: I'm not sure what setup you're using but seeing app.php return exceptions with the stack trace/logs in is a little troubling. This should only be in app_dev.php and not on production. Also, I'd recommend always developing on an environment as close as possible to your production stack. I'd suggest having a look at Vagrant. In regards to the error, have you cleared the cache? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but I assume you are echoing or using Twig to "render" an object, which in turn is it calling __toString. My assumption is it is throwing a GenerationError. Can you post your code

Comment: @Alex L Note that when the second parameter is set to true in `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);` of app.php, then you have more details in the error displayed as if you were on dev environment. Also, I deleted the prod cache folder. I'll edit my post to add my code

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to figure out what was wrong. Actually, I had to make sure the images files were available online. Since I used symlink option on my local environment et used

> {{ image('bundles/app/images/img.jpg').forceResize(x,y) }}

code to make a link to my images, after uploading my images from /public folder, I had to make a hard copy of my images on /web/bundles/app/images/ folder. I tried to run assets:install --symlink online, but for some reason it didn't work.